# What does $\sim$ mean in math and statistics?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

For example in the following picture above, the red sentence means what exactly with this $\sim$ symbol?

[image]

Comment: It is shorthand for the relation of a random variable to its probability distribution.  Here $X$ is a normally distributed variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Mathematics especially the part saying: *In statistics and probability theory, the tilde means "is distributed as"*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this context, $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ means that $X$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

This notation is used when $X$ follows some "well-known" distribution. For instance, you might also see $X\sim\exp(\lambda)$, which means that $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: Doesn't it specifically refer to asymptotics?

Comment: That's another use of the symbol $\sim$, but in probability $\sim$ is generally used as described in my answer.

Comment: I meant that it means the random variable is asymptotically distributed. That is, for sufficiently large $n$, the random variable, in this case, it is normally distributed. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: How could one random variable be asymptotically distributed? There needs to be a limiting operation.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern  There's no $n$.

Comment: Points well taken.

Comment: Different branches of mathematics give so many common symbols their own distinctive meaning.  It is confusing, but you often have to rely on context to interpret an expression.  Still, $\sim$ is most often held to mean some form of "equivalence" relation.  In probability theory that is: "the random variable belongs to a given equivalence class of paramatised probability distributions," and in this case, "$X$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$."

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern the accepted symbol for "asymptotically converges to" is "$\asymp$"  (unless I misunderstood what you mean by "asymptotics")

Answer (score 15):

I figured it's worth answering the title question more broadly...

As a general rule, the symbol $\sim$ can be read as "behaves like" or "behaves according to".

In Statistics, it is used to indicate that a variable follows a certain distribution. So, for example, $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ can be read as "$X$ behaves according to a Normal distribution". This is the usage relevant in the image in question.

It can be used to express approximation of size of a number - $x\sim y$ can be read as "$x$ is of the same order of magnitude as $y$", and thus they behave similarly in a sense. It is often used in physics to say things like $c\sim 10^8 \text{ ms}^{-1}$, which you can see is not particularly "accurate" as an approximation (as you would expect with $\approx$), but gives a sense of the order of magnitude.

It is also often used to indicate that two things are equivalent in some way. For example, if two triangles are similar triangles, you might have $\Delta ABC\sim \Delta DEF$.

Comment: I find this to be more complete than the accepted answer. A telltale sign is its latex symbol: "\sim", i.e. "is similar to". My only small pedantic point would be where you say "$c \sim 10^8 ms^{-1}$", I would add "compare this to the expression $c \approx 10^8 ms^{-1}$  meaning 'approximately equal to that value' (e.g. subject to experimental error / limitations etc)", to make clear that with $\sim$ we're not talking about a similarity in 'value' but in 'behaviour / magnitude'. (and it also makes the difference between two very similar-looking operators clear).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - it's more "complete" because it's not focused on the specific question being asked, but rather, is a broader answer for those who might come to this question looking for the answer to the title question. The accepted answer is the "right" answer for the question being asked in the content of the question.

Comment: It is unfortunate that some physicists use ~ to mean "same order of magnitude" or "scales with" because this is precisely the meaning of big-O (see Bachmann-Landau notation), whereas \sim instead denotes exact asymptotic equality.